# Listings package behaving weird with asterisks

Tags: xetex, listings

I have an output from R (which is a plain text) that I want to typeset using the `listings` package. The plain text file involves using special characters like asterisks and quotation marks together and that's where the trouble is happening. Please see the figure below.

[image]

For comparison, I typeset the text file using `listings` package (below) and the `verbatim` environment (above). You can see that the annotated part differs from the two. How can I fix this?

(FYI: I use XeTeX to compile my documents.)

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\textbf{VERBATIM}.

\begin{verbatim}
Call:
lm(formula = nettfa ~ inc + age, data = subset(data, fsize == 
    1))

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 44.68 on 2014 degrees of freedom
\end{verbatim}

\textbf{LISTINGS}.

\begin{lstlisting}
Call:
lm(formula = nettfa ~ inc + age, data = subset(data, fsize == 
    1))

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 44.68 on 2014 degrees of freedom
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

**Follow up**

Adding this code to the preamble solved my problem:

```
\begingroup % properly typesets UNICODE in listings
\catcode0=12 %
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\lst@DefEC{%
\lst@CCECUse\lst@ProcessLetter
‘’% *** add Unicode characters ***
^^00% end marker
}%
\endgroup
```

Comment: Thanks! Modifying the code from the answer solved my problem